# C++ inheritance getting error

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out this error I have. So I have a Person class, and a Student subclass.

The Person class has the following constructor:

```
Person(const string &name)
        {   this->name = name;
        }
```

The Student class has the following constructor:

```
Student::Student(const string &name, int regNo)
{ this->name = name;
  this->regNo = regNo;
}
```

When I try to compile the Student class though, I get this error for the constructor:

> In constructor 'Student::Student(const string&, int)':
>
> error: no matching function for call to 'Person::Person()'

I'm new to C++, so I have no idea why I get this error, but it has something to do with the inheritance of Person obviously.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are attempting to call `Person`'s default constructor, but it doesn't have one. In any case, it looks like what you want to do is call its single parameter constructor:

```
Student::Student(const string& name, int regNo) : Person(name), regNo(regNo)
{
}
```

Similarly, use the constructor initialization list in `Person`'s consructor:

```
Person(const string& name) : name(name) {}
```

This way, you are *initializing* your data members to the desired value, instead of default initializing them and then *assigning* them new values.

Answer (score 6):

You need to delegate to the correct ctor from the base class like this:

```
Student::Student(const string &name, int regNo)
    : Person( name )
{
  this->regNo = regNo;
}
```

Note that this uses initializer lists, so you could use the more idiomatic

```
Student::Student(const string &name, int regNo)
    : Person( name ), regNo( regNo )
{
}
```

and for the `Person` ctor:

```
Person(const string &name)
    : name( name )
{
}
```

The initializer list is used to initialize base classes and the member variables, everything you don't explicitly put in there is default constructed (and in your code, it is later assigned in the ctor's body). Since `Person` is not default constructible, you *must* initialize it in the initializer list.